# MySQL how to repeat query for every value in a column

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, foreach

This is an example of the tables and the columns used:

```
t_values:
╔════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Serial     ║ Date          ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1234214    ║ 2010.11.01... ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ ABC9123213 ║ 2001.01.01... ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ ...        ║ ...           ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╝

t_devices:
╔════════════╦══════╗
║ Serial     ║ Type ║
╠════════════╬══════╣
║ 1234214    ║ 2    ║
╠════════════╬══════╣
║ ABC9123213 ║ 13   ║
╠════════════╬══════╣
║ ...        ║ ...  ║
╚════════════╩══════╝
```

I have this query to get count values grouped by weaks, but also separated by the `Type` field:

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(V.Date), '/', WEEK(V.Date)) AS Yearweek, COUNT(*) AS QTY, D.TypeID
FROM 
t_values    AS V
JOIN 
t_devices   AS D 
ON V.Serial = D.Serial
WHERE D.TypeID = 1 --This is what I change manually
GROUP BY Yearweek
ORDER BY YEAR(V.Date) ASC, WEEK(V.Date) ASC
;
```

This `D.TypeID` column has about 13 distinct values so I need to manually change it for every value and re-run the query.

But clearly this is an anti-DRY approach. Since I'm new with MySQL I have the basic ideas about writing these kind of "*static*" queries but I have no particular experience or idea about the proper solutions for some more dynamic conditions.

I know of the possibility of stored procedures. Is it something that I should try to use exactly for problems like this, or is there some simpler, built-in tool to iterate this query with the different distinct values of a choosen column instead?

**Edit:** I was asked to clarify how would I even need the results, since I could just group by the `Yearkweek` column as well and leave the `WHERE` part. Only that it would just give me one big table with the `Yearweek-TypeID` pairs.

I need the query I've posted with their actual own separate Type results, maybe ran dynamically after one another. And maybe I'll call this query with another language or implement it with an ORM and save the results into dataframes or excels every time on query is done.

So I am just not sure which direction is the preferred one. Should I use a variable and loop that with the language I run the SQL query with or create the procedure with native MySQL beforehand an call that.

Comment: Group by yearweek,type and lose the where?

Comment: @P.Salmon If I'm not mistaken that would create yeareak, type pairs. Should I group again for tpye as well to get the result for one type at a time?

Comment: You are correct all yearweek,type pairs would appear in the result. Is that not what you want? Can you clarify what you mean by dynamic - is it that the number of types can vary or that you want to vary the number of times you wish to run the query or do you want to run this query for all types but one type at a time?

Comment: @P.Salmon That is hard to say, maybe I don't have the clearest idea how should I handle the results. I would say I need the query I've posted with their own separate Type results, only ran dynamically after one another. And maybe I'll call this query with another language or implement it with an ORM and save the results into dataframes or excels every time on query is done. But getting the whole thing in one result query with pairs would leave me with the very same situation I guess.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not sure what do you mean. I posted my query and my question is a theoretical one. As I've said I've done the double grouping already but that's not what I wanted. I may go out and do a procudere myself of course, but that would still not perfectly answer if that is the best approach to my problem.

Comment: I guess we'll have to stick with this mutual misunderstanding

Comment: @Strawberry I've updated my question, maybe that's what you are refering to, the same thing P.Salmon asked about. If you downvoted the question, I'm sorry, I'll try to clarify the question to be useful for others as well. The problem is that I've only used MySQL for manual queries but I am at the point where I need to automatically run the same queries for many different intervals again and again. I'm just not familiar with the in-built MySQL tools for this need.

Comment: Honestly, if there was any improvement here, I would act accordingly.

Comment: Or maybeI just don't understand it. It is your answer, in your perspective I believe it is very specific, but from mine it is not. I simply don't understand what more would you need. Also sometimes even knowing the actual question is a hard time for a rookie with a new technology. I have made a sample of the columns used. I put my query there and named my problem as detailed as I could. I read, now I'm not sure you read mine. Clearly I have no intention not the clarify, but until you point out which part is missing this is just unhelfpul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the data in one result this way:

```
SELECT D.TypeID,
       CONCAT(YEAR(V.Date), '/',
       WEEK(V.Date)) AS Yearweek, COUNT(*) AS QTY, D.TypeID
FROM 
t_values    AS V
JOIN 
t_devices   AS D 
ON V.Serial = D.Serial
GROUP BY D.TypeID, Yearweek
ORDER BY D.TypeID,YEAR(V.Date) ASC, WEEK(V.Date) ASC
;
```

Or you can take input using a bound variable,

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(V.Date), '/', WEEK(V.Date)) AS Yearweek, COUNT(*) AS QTY, D.TypeID
FROM 
t_values    AS V
JOIN 
t_devices   AS D 
ON V.Serial = D.Serial
WHERE D.TypeID = ?
GROUP BY Yearweek
ORDER BY YEAR(V.Date) ASC, WEEK(V.Date) ASC
;
```

How you supply the variable is going to depend on what you are using to call SQL.

You can create a stored procedure.  The great way to call stored procedures is with a bound variable, but you could pass the argument by generating an SQL string with the argument.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE type_data
(IN type_in INTEGER)
BEGIN
  SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(V.Date), '/', WEEK(V.Date)) AS Yearweek, COUNT(*) AS QTY, D.TypeID
  FROM 
  t_values    AS V
  JOIN 
  t_devices   AS D 
  ON V.Serial = D.Serial
  WHERE D.TypeID = type_in
  GROUP BY Yearweek
  ORDER BY YEAR(V.Date) ASC, WEEK(V.Date) ASC
END
;

CALL type_data(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas Marlin. To be exact and help clarify my issue, I'm using Python, even `SQLAlchemy` to reimplement my native SQL queries later. I'll need the results in separate dataframes or excel tables, I was just not sure how should I create loop-like programs with queries. Should I already implement it with the query logic or outsource it to Python. The multiple `group by` solution was done already by me and I realized that I would just need to group again to get the solution again for separate types to separate result tables.